# Need to insert rows into table based on information pulled from table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2010

I need to populate a table based on rows from another table. We will call the table that must be populated table A, and then table used for populating, table B.

Table B has columns for the customer ID, and the amount of different transaction types they have done (for example Sold, Purchased, Exchanged).

Table A has columns for the customer ID, the name of the transaction (Sold, Purchased, Exchanged), and a column for whether or not they have ever done that transaction. Whether or not they have done that transaction will be decided by the amount of times they have done that transaction, as recorded in table B. So for example, if Customer 12 has sold 3 things, purchased 0 things, and exchanged 1 thing, then they would have:
-One row in table B 
-Three rows in table A, with true for sold, false for purchased, and true for exchanged.

Can anyone help me start out a basic structure for this? I have never had to populate another table based on results of another one before, so this seems a little daunting to me and I'm not sure where I should really start.

I am using Microsoft Access 2010.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: In table B, would customer 12 have 2 rows? 1 for sold and 1 for exchanged? I'm just trying to get a handle on the table layout. Or are the columns in table B: customer_id, times_sold, times_purch, times_exch?

Comment: @Lisa Customer 12 would have 3 rows, 1 for sold, 1 for exchanged, and 1 for purchased (except purchased would say false or something similar).

Comment: Ok -- but what about table B, the source table?

Comment: And does this need to populate a second table? Is there a specific reason why this couldn't be a standard query of Table B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the source data in table B is all in one row, so your fields are customer_id, sold, purc, exch. I'm also assuming that you do want to populate table A with this data. If your table B data is in multiple rows, let me know and I'll revise this. If you just want to write a query and not populate the new table, remove the outer SELECT ... INTO statement.

```
SELECT customer_id, trans_type, trans_status INTO A
FROM (
      SELECT customer_id
          , "SOLD" AS trans_type
          , SWITCH (sold = 0, "FALSE", sold > 0, "TRUE") AS trans_status  
      FROM B
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_id
          , "PURCHASED" AS trans_type
          , SWITCH (purc = 0, "FALSE", purc > 0, "TRUE") AS trans_status  
      FROM B
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_id
          , "EXCHANGED" AS trans_type
          , SWITCH (exch = 0, "FALSE", exch > 0, "TRUE") AS trans_status  
      FROM B
      ORDER BY customer_id, trans_type
 )
```

Comment: @Lisa this is perfect. Thank you! I didn't know there was a SWITCH keyword!